# How to load sorl-thumbnails files in templates?

Tags: python, django, sorl-thumbnail

I have question how to load media in my template

I use sorl-thumbnails to create thumbnails 
and I want to show the picture in template

Here is my settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT= os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIAFILES_DIRS = (
    ("cache", os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT,'cache')),
)
```

my templates :  english/maininfo.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load thumbnail %}


<ul id="menu">
    <li>
        {% thumbnail "http://www.test/img/logo.png" "100x80"  as im %}
        <img src="{{ im.url  }}" width="{{ im.width }}" height="{{ im.height }}">
        {% endthumbnail %}
    </li>
```

there is error :

```
The current URL, media/cache/d8/fe/d8fe70d567ce1a03769de7db30634696.jpg, didn't match any of these.
```

But I really have this directory

this is the project structure 
[image]

and my views.py

```
def maininfo(request):
    responseContext = {'lang':request.LANGUAGE_CODE,}
    return render(request, 'english/maininfo.html',responseContext)
```

How to load media files in templates??
Please help me! Thank you very much